# inkjet with self-cleaning inkjets? (for occasional printing)

Tags: printer, hardware-rec

i'm looking for a cheap printer - i'm not printing very much so it should be rather cheap 
i had a canon pixma inket so far but it always suffered of dried-up inkjets (i mostly only print each 2-3 month).

so here's my questions:

- is there a any inket printer which has self-cleaning jets which don't dry up when using only occasionly? (a shop assistant claimed the hp officejet 6500 could do this)
- in case of a laserprinter, i've been to go for one of those: brother HL-2140 or HL-2035
  as it seems perfect for cheap noname-toner - recommended?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't hear about a self-cleaning system in printers before.
The "self-cleaning" tool in the "Printer Maintenance" tab (usually located in the HP printer manager software) doesn't really clean clogged inks.

There is a [manual way](http://www.ehow.com/how_5993673_clean-hp-printer-jets.html) to clean your printer ink jets. It should do the job.

*About the second question - unfortunately it's forbidden (regard to the FAQ) to ask for shopping or buying recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at printers that have print heads on the ink cartridges themselves, The cartridge will be a little more expensive, but you'll get new printhead with each cartridge.

Many HPs , some lower end Canons, as well as lexmark and Dell printers have this feature.